# Dissappeared files from external disk, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: external-hdd, hidden-files

My files from an external disk disappeared suddenly. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I am sure that I didn't delete them!

One the external disk I can see some files, but some files I can't see. My external disk was on a table (it was not hit or turned out). A very important folder is missing. Has anyone some idea what can I do?

Comment: Try this, check the health of the drive (ie. `smartctl` or equivalent using drive electronics & not touching the platters/data area at all to assess health & consider action plan in a way that won't harm anything on drive). Next I'd probably `fsck` or perform local checks on file-system (file system check), then I'd probably run `badblocks`

Comment: Which filesystem type is used on the external drive (ext4, ntfs) and how is the drive mounted? You can check with `findmnt`-command. Usually we have backups of important files and folders, that makes it easy to recover from any kind of accidents.

Comment: Thank you guys on help. I found files in some other folder. I deleted a few files, but I have no idea how that was affected to move other files. I think that my external disk need change after reading comments.